# Returning a missing element from a string of integers

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function that accepts an array of unique integers between 0 and 9 (inclusive), and returns the missing element. Here's what I've got. So near but so far.

```
var currentPlace = 0;

function getMissingElement(superImportantArray){
    while (currentPlace < 9){
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var arrayNum = superImportantArray[currentPlace]
            if (i == arrayNum) {
                currentPlace ++;
                console.log("so it's not " + i);
            }
            else if (i !=arrayNum) {
                console.log("try..." + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
// run
var myArray = [0,5,1,3,2,9,7,6,4]; // this test should return 8
getMissingElement(myArray);
```

I'm not sure i'm approaching this correctly. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What does your function currently return/log? Why do you thing it doesn't work?

Comment: An alternative is that you could loop over the array, put the value into a new array at the position it would by if it were an index...and then find the first empty index

Comment: Here's more or less how I'd handle it: http://jsfiddle.net/byKLP/ - note how it doesn't require nested loops

Comment: @FelixKling it very crudely logs everything apart from the missing element. Which is kind of right, but I can't see how to out put the number 8 after all that.

Comment: @ian great job Ian, thanks a lot, very neat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to post my answer from the comments. A simpler way to handle this, in my opinion, is to loop over the original array, and flag a new array at the index that they represent. For example, if the number is 4, flag the 4th index in the new array. The reason for all this is because once this is done, **one** index should be left unflagged. All that would be left to do is find the unflagged index.

Here's an example (I commented the code here, not the fiddle):

```
function findMissing(array, min, max) {
    var missing, unfilledArray, i, j;

    // Array to hold the flags
    unfilledArray = [];

    for (i = min, j = max; i <= j; i++) {
        // Flag the index in the new array with the current value
        unfilledArray[array[i]] = true;
    }

    for (i = min, j = max; i <= j; i++) {
        // Loop over new array and find the unflagged index
        currentUnfilled = unfilledArray[i];
        if (!currentUnfilled) {
            // Current index not flagged
            missing = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    return missing;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/6GAyw/

The other little feature I added was that you explicitly specify the minimum and maximum value, which, in your case, is 0 and 9. This feature allows this solution to be used on any range of numbers (unlike my original comment/suggestion).

And not that I fully understand big O notation, but I believe this is O(2n), not O(n^2), since there aren't nested loops/`indexOf`.

---

If you were looking to get all missing numbers in a range, you can easily modify the function to return an array of unflagged indexes instead. Here's an example:

```
function findMissing(array, min, max) {
    var missing, unfilledArray, i, j;

    // Array to hold the missing numbers
    missing = [];
    // Array to hold the flags
    unfilledArray = [];

    for (i = min, j = max; i <= j; i++) {
        // Flag the index in the new array with the current value
        unfilledArray[array[i]] = true;
    }

    for (i = min, j = max; i <= j; i++) {
        // Loop over new array and find the unflagged index
        currentUnfilled = unfilledArray[i];
        if (!currentUnfilled) {
            // Current index not flagged
            missing.push(i);
        }
    }

    return missing;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/zFS89/

Answer (score 1):

```
function getMissingElement(superImportantArray){
    var result = [], length = Math.max(10, superImportantArray.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(superImportantArray.indexOf(i) == -1){
            result.push(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Try this. This will return an array of missing elements else return an empty array.
[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hMgxG/)

Comment: This is inefficient. I believe it's technically O(n^2), because of the `indexOf` inside of the loop, when it shouldn't need to be. And you've provided no explanation or fiddle. And the OP asked for a number returned, not an array

Answer (score 1):

So here is one way to do it: Since you know that the array only contains values from `0` to `9`, you can build a "set" of numbers and remove each "seen" value in the array from the set:

```
function getMissingElement(superImportantArray){
    var numbers = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        numbers[i] = true
    }

    for (var i = 0, l = superImportantArray.length; i < l; i++) {
        delete numbers[superImportantArray[i]];
    }

    return Object.keys(numbers);
}
```

This would return an array of all numbers that are missing. If there can always only be one missing number you can easily modify this to directly return the number instead.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
function getMissingElement(arrayTest) {
    // create an array with all digits
    var digitsArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    var index;
    for (var i=0; i<arrayTest.length; i++) {
         // get the index of current digit on our array
         index = digitsArray.indexOf(arrayTest[i]);
         // if found, remove it from our array.
         if (index >= 0) {
             digitsArray.splice(index,1);
         }
    }
    // the last remaining digit in the original array should be the one missing.
    return (digitsArray[0]);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, really appreciate the comments.

Comment: I know, comments can save a lot of time by explaining what the code does.

Answer (score 0):

This one is better for the eyes.

```
function getMissingElement(superImportantArray) {
 return superImportantArray.reduce(function (sum, value) {return sum - value;}, 45);
}
```